# How to do calculation inside case_when()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to multiply values with two different factors conditionally, let's say times 10, if values are <7, and times 5, if values are >= 7.

I tried to use case_when inside mutate and across, but it didn't work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- as_tibble(iris)

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(across(1:4, ~ case_when(. < 7 ~ * 10, . >= 7 ~ * 5)))
```

Is this even possible with case_when()?

Comment: You forgot to add the  `.` in multiplication i.e. `df %>%
  mutate(across(1:4, ~ case_when(. < 7 ~ .* 10, . >= 7 ~ . * 5)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  mutate(across(1:4, ~ case_when(.x < 7 ~ .x * 10,
                                 .x >= 7 ~ .x * 5))) %>%
  head(10)
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1            51          35           14           2  setosa
#> 2            49          30           14           2  setosa
#> 3            47          32           13           2  setosa
#> 4            46          31           15           2  setosa
#> 5            50          36           14           2  setosa
#> 6            54          39           17           4  setosa
#> 7            46          34           14           3  setosa
#> 8            50          34           15           2  setosa
#> 9            44          29           14           2  setosa
#> 10           49          31           15           1  setosa
```